# How to know how the docker container is started

Tags: docker, docker-compose

A few containers which are started from a docker-compose file are running on the VM.
but I don't know where is the docker-compose file,  how to figure it out?

Furthermore, If there is a container start using "docker run", how to check the parameters used by "docker run"?

Answer (score 3):

Show running containers:

```
docker ps
```

Get Configurations of docker container

```
docker inspect <containerid>
```

Parsing the output to get only the run-command:

```
docker inspect <containerid> | jq -r '.[0]["Config"]["Cmd"][0]'
```

For your second part of question regarding finding the docker file:

```
docker inspect <containerid> | jq -r '.[0]["Config"]["Labels"]["com.docker.compose.project.working_dir"]'
```

Comment: Thanks.  but I don't think it solves my problem.  I would like to know which compose file is used by a running container. I can't check all the compose file on the machine.  and I can't search all the compose file in the file system, the file may be in a folder I don't have access right.

The 2nd question is,  if I stop a container,  rebuild it.  I would like to start the container again using "docker run" with the same parameters,  how can I do that.  I don't think "docker inspect" give this information directly.

Comment: Hi i just edited my post. The second grep commands should do this.

Comment: hmm, I don't have compose.project.working_dir and compose.config_files
here is my output

********************************
 docker inspect f8b5e2d46ece | grep compose
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "aea3d925be0cddea645a6640cf3a1565b5b1576c28bf61d7baa179732b1c9f59",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "3",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "worker",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "1.24.0-rc1",

Comment: regarding another one, ["Config"]["Cmd"] doesn't contains the information I need.  For example, I start a contaner "docker run -e foo="bar" -v /tmp:/tmp --rm -d <imageid>" ,  so I can see from docker inspect out that foo="bar" is set in ["Config"]["Env"], and /tmp:/tmp is in ["Mounts"],  but there is not a place to show that the container start with   '-e foo="bar" -v /tmp:/tmp --rm -d'

Comment: Is it possbile my docker and cocker-compose are too old?  I still use docker 18.09, and docker-compose 1.24 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use -f, --format to save the use of jq.

Credits to https://forums.rancher.com/t/how-to-list-container-ip-with-docker-inspect-format/13044

```sh
docker inspect --format='{{index .Config.Labels "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir"}}' CONTAINER_ID
```